# HTTP request using cURL after queuing in Laravel returns null

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am trying to get response from Instagram API by using curl, here is my code:

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" . $media->media_id . "/comments?access_token=" . $this->accessToken;
$comments = $this->runCurl($url);
```

here is the function running curll:

```
public function runCurl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $results = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($results == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return $results->data;
}
```

push to queue:

```
$job = (new InstagramCommentsCrawler($this->currentUserId, $accessToken));
$this->dispatch($job);
```

run the queue using:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

when I run this code without queuing it works fine, but after queuing the results of curl is null.

Is there anything wrong or a way to solve this?

Comment: I **think** PHP over the command line uses a different configuration file to when it's running over the web as usual. Perhaps CURL isn't enabled for CLI, which could explain the difference. Have you tried using Guzzle by the way? It should be installed in Laravel by default, that should hopefully give you more useful error messages.

Comment: Also, have you tried `echo`ing the `$url` variable passed to `runCurl`? It might be that there's something wrong with that.

Comment: @Jonathon, Thanks for suggesting Guzzle. Yes, I tried logging, nothing is wrong with parameters. even I used `file_get_contents()` instead of running curl but it returns null.

Comment: No problem. Okay,  can you possibly try using `curl_error` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to show any extra information about what, if anything failed? `file_get_contents` could also fail due to the PHP CLI settings, it requires `allow_url_fopen` to be turned on.

Comment: did you manage to solve it ? i got same issue  queue processes but nothing sends in curl